# Find out if $f''(0)$ exist and $x=0$ is a inflection point

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Let $f(x)=\begin{cases} \displaystyle\sin(\frac{1}{x})\cdot e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}} &\text{for } x \neq 0\\0 &\text{dla } x=0 \end{cases}$

Find out if $f''(0)$ exist and $x=0$ is a inflection point

I not sure if my method is correct I want to use taylor expansion but it's as $x\to \infty$ we have $T(x)=\displaystyle \frac{1}{x}-\frac{7}{6x^3}+o(x^3)$ and from here we see that $f''(x)=0$ and $f'''(x) \neq 0$ and can I conclude that from these $f''(0)=0$ and since $f'''(0)\neq0$ but $f''(0)=0$ so $x=0$ is a inflection point?

Comment: Try differentiating twice? And what do you mean intersection, intersection of what with what?

Comment: sorry It should be inflection point

Comment: Btw, you have to calculate the derivative by the limit definition at $x=0$.

Comment: OK I know how to show $f''(0)$ exist but have problem with inflection point, any ideas ?

Comment: If you calculate the derivative, you know exactly whether it is an inflection point or not.

Comment: how ? and need to know whether it change sign but it's hard to figure out since f'' has ugly form